# TESTNG Consistent execution of the test groups

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

Сreated methods:

```
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"INdependent"})
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"dependent"})
@Test (groups = {"INdependent"})
@Test (groups = {"dependent"}, dependsOnGroups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterMethod(groups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterMethod(groups = {"dependent"})
@AfterGroups(groups = {"INdependent"})
@AfterGroups(groups = {"dependent"})
```

Expected:

```
- BeforeGroups = "INdependent"
 - Test = "INdependent"
 - AfterMethod = "INdependent"
- AfterGroups = "INdependent"
- BeforeGroups = "dependent"
 - Test = "dependent"
 - AfterMethod = "dependent"
- AfterGroups = "dependent"
```

Actual:

```
- BeforeGroups = "INdependent"
 - Test = "INdependent"
 - AfterMethod = "dependent"     (этого тут быть не должно)
 - AfterMethod = "INdependent"
- AfterGroups = "INdependent"
- BeforeGroups = "dependent"
 - Test = "dependent"
 - AfterMethod = "dependent"
 - AfterMethod = "INdependent"   (этого тут быть не должно)
- AfterGroups = "dependent"
```

What am I doing wrong?

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="mts-sorm3-extractor-tests">
   <groups>
       <run>
           <include name="independent"/>
           <include name="dependent"/>
       </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="ru.mts.sorm.mts_sorm3_extractor_tests.Sorm3ExtractDictTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- mts-sorm3-extractor-tests -->
</suite> <!-- Custom suite -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups are used for tests selection. When you ask for `independent` and `dependent` groups then **all** methods with one of this 2 groups will be run.

That's why `@AfterMethod(groups = {"INdependent"})` and `@AfterMethod(groups = {"dependent"})` are called for every test methods of the class.

The good solution will be to move `independent` test in a class and `dependent` in another class.